# Laravel Efficient way to retrieve records on poor shared hosting server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

For the moment, I'm working on a really poor shared hosting server, therefore I have limitations. One of my database tables increases it's records daily by about 2000. These records are basically the search results and for that I use Laravel's paginator. It has reached a point where to retrieve all of the records without getting a 500 error, I've had to remove columns from the select query.

I was wondering if there is another way to use the paginator without having to retrieve everything from the table, or if there is a more efficient way to get all the records from the table using Eloquent or the Query Builder.

Here is my code:

```
$results = Model::select('table.col1', 'table.col2', 'table.col3', 'table.col4',
            'table.col5', 
            'table.col6',
            'table.col7', 
            'table.col8',
            'table.col9', 
            'table.col10', 'table_two.col1', 'table_three.companyName')
            ->leftjoin('table_three as tt', 'tt.col1', '=', 'table.col2')
            ->leftjoin('table_two', 'table_two.col1', '=', 'table.col1')
            ->where('table.col3', 2)->where('table.col11', 1)
            ->orderBy('col2', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();


$currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();
$col = new Collection($final_results);
$perPage = 50;
$currentPageSearchResults = $col->slice(($currentPage - 1) * $perPage, $perPage)->all();
$entries = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageSearchResults, count($col), $perPage);

return $entries;
```

Any ideas? Or is the only way to upgrade the server?

Comment: Did you put indexes on the "where" columns? That is a composite index on table "table" on col3 and col11 in this order.

Comment: And indexes on the columns used by the left join in the on clause even more important then the WHERE clause columns.. you should generate a SQL with the toSQL() function and run a EXPLAIN [query] on that in PHPMyAdmin if you are using that. And post the results of EXPLAIN [query] here..

Comment: And as Raymond said, add also indexes on "tt.col1" and "table_two.col1"

Comment: I would avoid Elloquent cause is inefficient. Probably your error is that you are hitting the maximum_execution_time or memory exhausted. I have solved similar issues in this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46237668/6329802

Comment: you could use the laravel debugbar to help see the full list of SQL queries being used. Eloquent can perform many queries or subqueries

Comment: @valicu2000 and @Raymond Njiland (I think this is what you mean) I can't add unique indexes because many of the columns have identical values :/ `col1` is the same as `id` so it's already unique

Comment: @Adam Silva: who said anything about "unique index"??? We were talking about simple indexes

Comment: @valicu2000 My bad, I understood wrong. I've added the indexes on the mentioned columns, and it helped, but not by a lot..